# Bundle JDK, environment variables setting, tomcat, mysql and app war file to an installer

Tags: installation, desktop-application

I developed an application which uses tomcat and mysql.

And now my query is:
Is it possible to bundle JDK, environment variables setting, tomcat, mysql and app war file to an installer so that i can ship as a desktop product across multiple OS's?

Thanks in advance.
-Ratan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

First you need to decide on a setup authoring tool: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software

For example, Advanced Installer has a dedicated project type for Tomcat applications. After that, you can try creating the package you need. You can then ask more specific questions if you encounter problems.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Let me try and revert back if i find any problems in using these...